# How can I de-concatenate a Linked List into 3 separate Link Lists in C?

Tags: c, split, concatenation, singly-linked-list, function-definition

so I'm pretty new to Data Structures and I'm just getting introduced to Singly Linked List. The task I have right now, is to:

1. Concatenate 3x Linked Lists into a single Linked List
2. De-Concatenate the large Linked List back to 3x Linked Lists.

I have managed to do the first step, I create 3 separate Linked Lists and then append them with eachother. But I'm running into a small problem at the De-Concatenation stage and I'm hoping someone can explain what I'm doing wrong. First and foremost, here's my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} node;

node * createLL(int);
void displayLL(node * head);
node * concatenate(node * head1, node * head2, node * head3);
void deconcatenate(node * head1, node * head2, node * head3);

int main() {

struct node * head1 = NULL;
struct node * head2 = NULL;
struct node * head3 = NULL;
printf("Creating #1 Link List.. \n");
head1 = createLL(5);
displayLL(head1);

printf("\nCreating #2 Link List .. \n");
head2 = createLL(5);
displayLL(head2);

printf("\nCreating #3 Link List .. \n");
head3 = createLL(5);
displayLL(head3);

printf("\nConcatenating the Three Link Lists");
head1 = concatenate(head1,head2,head3);
displayLL(head1);

printf("\nDe-Concatenating the Link List into 3 Link Lists");
deconcatenate(head1,head2,head3);

printf("\nList #1\n");
displayLL(head1);
printf("\nList #2\n");
displayLL(head2);
printf("\nList #3\n");
displayLL(head3);

}

    void deconcatenate(node * head1, node * head2, node * head3) {
struct node * temp1;
struct node * temp2;
struct node * temp3;

int i,j,k;
i = j = k = 0;

temp1 = head1;

while (i < 5) {
    temp1 = temp1->next;
    i++;
}
head2 = temp1; // 6
temp1 = NULL;

temp2 = head2;

while (j < 5) {
    temp2 = temp2->next;
    j++;
}
head3 = temp2;
temp2 = NULL;

temp3 = head3;

while (k < 5) {
    temp3 = temp3->next;
    k++;
}
temp3 = NULL;

}

void displayLL(node * HEAD) {
    for(node * p = HEAD; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        printf("%d->",p->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

node * concatenate(node * head1, node * head2, node * head3) {
struct node * temp = head1;

while (temp->next != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
}

temp->next = head2;

while (temp->next != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
}

temp->next = head3;

return head1;

}

node * createLL(int n) {

int i = 0;
struct node * head = NULL;
struct node * temp = NULL;
struct node * p = NULL;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("Enter data in Node #%d",i);
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
    } else {
        p = head;
        while (p->next != NULL) {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = temp;
    }

}

return head;

}
```

**And here's the output**

[image]

As you can see, after **De-Concatenation**, LinkList #1 only has "1" node while it should have nodes of value 1 to 5. LinkList #2 has way too many nodes than it should have. It should have nodes of value 6 to 10 but it has nodes from 6 to 15. Link List #3 is the only one with accurate value of nodes.

So what am I doing wrong in the **deconcatenate Function**?

Comment: What is the criteria or condition of the de-concatenation of a list?

Comment: The linklist (head1) is 15 node-long and I need to split it into 3x linked lists, each having 5 nodes. That is about it.

Answer (score 0):

The while loops inside your `void deconcatenate()`, shouldn't their conditions be `less than` other than `equal to`? And beside you don't need to loop through the last list just to set the last element's next pointer to `NULL` because you already did that when you created the very first linked list.

Comment: Yeah, I replaced the condition from i == 5 to i < 5 and did the same to j,k - but now, the program just crashes once it reaches to the deconcatenate function. Now, the first while loop runs as it should but then it crashes.

Comment: @VenoM in your while loop, when i == 4 and after the code is run, temp1 points to the 6th node. So by assigning head2 to the next of temp1, you actually assigned head2 to point to the 7th node. You can now either just do head2 = temp1 or decrease the number of loops, there are many ways of doing this. And as I said above, you don't need to loop through the last list.

Comment: Updated the code in the original post, but it's still not giving the desired output..

Output is: Link #1: 1 to 15
Link #2: 6 to 15
Link #3: 11 to 15

Comment: @VenoM it's because you set the temp1 to NULL while temp1 is just the temporary variable. You should instead set the `next` of the 5th node to NULL. That then, terminates correctly the first linked list at the end of the 5th node.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the assignment is too difficult for a beginner.

If you are going to build a list from other three lists by concatenating their nodes then pointers to head nodes of the three lists shall be passed by reference because the lists will being changed within the function `concatenate`.

That is after calling the function the three lists shall be empty.

In C passing an object by reference to a function means passing the object indirectly through a pointer to it. In this case the function will have a direct access to the object by dereferencing the pointer that points to the object.

So the function should be declared at least like

```
node * concatenate(node ** head1, node ** head2, node ** head3);
```

The same considerations are aplayed to the function `deconcatenate`. After calling the function the original list shall be empty because its elements are being moved to three other lists.

That is the function should be declared at least like

```
void deconcatenate(node **source_head, node ** head1, node ** head2, node ** head3);
```

However these functions have too many parameters. As the both functions deal with a triple  of pointers to head nodes it will be better to declare a structure that has three data members that keep pointers to pointers to head nodes and to use an object of this structure as a functions' parameter.

For example

```
typedef struct triple_lists
{
    node **head1;
    node **head2;
    node **head3;
} triple_lists;
```

and

```
node * concatenate( triple_lists triple );
void deconcatenate( node **head, triple_lists triple );
```

As I have understood correctly the function `deconcatenate` shall split a source list into three other lists such a way that each list will contain adjacent elements of the source list and also the source list shall be divided into three more or less equal parts.

If so then approach can be the following. You need three pointers to nodes that will specify ends of each of the three lists. When the first pointer is advanced one time, the second pointer will be advanced two times and the third pointer will be advanced three times until the source node will not be exhausted.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct triple_lists
{
    node **head1;
    node **head2;
    node **head3;
} triple_lists;

int append( node **head, int data )
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( *new_node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        
        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;
        
        *head = new_node;
    }
    
    return success;
}

FILE * display( const node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

node * concatenate( triple_lists triple )
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node **current = &head;
    
    *current = *triple.head1;
    *triple.head1 = NULL;
    
    while ( *current != NULL ) current = &( *current )->next;
    
    *current = *triple.head2;
    *triple.head2 = NULL;

    while ( *current != NULL ) current = &( *current )->next;
    
    *current = *triple.head3;
    *triple.head3 = NULL;
    
    return head;
}

void deconcatenate( node **head, triple_lists triple )
{
    *triple.head1 = *head;
    *triple.head2 = *head;
    *triple.head3 = *head;
    
    triple_lists tails  = { head, head, head };

    while ( *tails.head3 != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; *tails.head1 != NULL && i < 1; i++ )
        {
            tails.head1 =  &( *tails.head1 )->next; 
        }
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; *tails.head2 != NULL && i < 2; i++ )
        {
            tails.head2 =  &( *tails.head2 )->next; 
        }
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; *tails.head3 != NULL && i < 3; i++ )
        {
            tails.head3 =  &( *tails.head3 )->next; 
        }
    }

    *head = NULL;
    
    *triple.head2 = *tails.head1;
    *tails.head1 = NULL;
    
    *triple.head3 = *tails.head2;
    *tails.head2 = NULL;
}

int main(void) 
{
    node *head1 = NULL;
    node *head2 = NULL;
    node *head3 = NULL;
    
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < 10 )
    {
        append( &head1, i++ );
    }
    
    while ( i < 15 )
    {
        append( &head2, i++ );
    }
    
    while ( i < 18 )
    {
        append( &head3, i++ );
    }
    
    printf( "list1: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head1, stdout ) );
    
    printf( "list2: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head2, stdout ) );
    
    printf( "list3: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head3, stdout ) );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    triple_lists triple = { &head1, &head2, &head3 };
    
    node *head0 = concatenate( triple );
    
    printf( "list0: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head0, stdout ) );
    
    printf( "list1: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head1, stdout ) );
    
    printf( "list2: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head2, stdout ) );
    
    printf( "list3: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head3, stdout ) );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    deconcatenate( &head0, triple );
    
    printf( "list0: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head0, stdout ) );
    
    printf( "list1: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head1, stdout ) );
    
    printf( "list2: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head2, stdout ) );
    
    printf( "list3: " );
    putc( '\n', display( head3, stdout ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
list1: 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
list2: 10 -> 11 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> null
list3: 15 -> 16 -> 17 -> null

list0: 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 15 -> 16 -> 17 -> null
list1: null
list2: null
list3: null

list0: null
list1: 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
list2: 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> null
list3: 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 15 -> 16 -> 17 -> null
```

I did not spend my time to write a function that clears a list freeing all the allocated memory. I hope you can write such a function yourself.